# Forbidden (403), when accessing server-status on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, http-status-code-403

I am trying to access Apache server-status?auto but it is giving me Forbidden 403 Message

I checked apache2.conf and there is this options under html directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
```

Has anybody came across this problem and was able to fix it?
Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more information...

PS: I already tried the solutions of the suggested question made by Shahar Galukman but the answers there didnt help me or i was not smart enough to understand.

Thanks for your patience

Comment: In addition to being an exact duplicate, this uses apache 2.2 (according to a tag), which is outdated (eol 2018-01-01).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/a/653642/875383

Please try this user approach once.

Comment: This should not be posted as an answer. Better to flag a duplicate in such cases.

Comment: Thanks, i used the line allow from all and it worked on the virtual host config and it worked.